# Managing poll answer in a spreadsheet: grouping same questions

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet created from a poll with 3 columns:
unique id, question, answer (a numeric value)

Data repeats several times for each user like this:

| User ID | Questions text | Answers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | question 1 | AnswerID1 |
| ID1 | question 2 | AnswerID1 |
| ID1 | question 3 | AnswerID1 |
| ID2 | question 1 | AnswerID2 |
| ID2 | question 2 | AnswerID2 |
| ID2 | question 3 | AnswerID2 |

Ideally I'd like to group all question 1, with all different answers on the same row or column, so it's easier to make a graph to show results.
Like this:

| Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AnwerID1 | AnwerID1 | AnwerID1 |
| AnwerID2 | AnwerID2 | AnwerID2 |

Any suggestion how it's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

Such a table transformation is not very complicated, it can be done with three simple formulas.

Put the formula `={"User ID";UNIQUE(A2:A)}` in cell E1 and you will get a column with the IDs of all users who completed the survey.

Now put the formula `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B))` in cell F1 and you will get a row with a list of all the questions - headers of columns for result table.

In cell F2 write the formula

`=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,IF(($E2=$A$2:$A)*(F$1=$B$2:$B),$C$2:$C,"")))`

This will return all answers from the first user to the first question. Yes, usually there is only one answer for each question in your original table. But believe me, this will not always be the case - someday you will encounter a situation where the user will have two or more answers to one question. This formula will allow you to see them all.

Now just drag this F2 cell to the right to the end of the question list, and then the entire formula row down to the end of the user list.

Comment: Thank you!! That worked very well. I had to adapt the third formula you wrote changing the commas to semicolons, but it worked well.
Also, I adapted it to use them in a new sheet, so I had to put the sheet references to ranges, but that was easy. Thank you

Comment: @ezellohar Please read [What should I do when someon answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)